# Cannot load example-component after installation of Vue.js to Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hello I have issue with running vue.js with laravel. I just installed fresh installation of laravel + vue and when I try to add example-component into my blade nothing happend... I am getting this error in console:

```
app.js:19073 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of undefined
    at Object../resources/js/app.js (app.js:19073)
```

Which refers to this line

```
Vue.component('example-component', __webpack_require__(/*! ./components/ExampleComponent.vue */ "./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue").default);
```

My app. js looks like this I changed nothing.

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue').default;
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

and in my blade I just using `<example-component> </example-component>` tag. And Yes in  js/components/ExampleComponent realy is example-component created. What else may be wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change app.js into this solved mz problem. Probably deafault app.js generated by laravel is for Vue2 and I am using Vue3

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';

require('./bootstrap');
let app=createApp({})
app.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
app.mount("#app")
```